# Is it possible to migrate data from Oracle to MariaDB using Glue?

Tags: oracle, mariadb, aws-glue

I am trying to do an outline on how to migrate data from Oracle to MariaDB using Glue and Lambda. I know I need to create an RDS database for Oracle and MariaDB then create a glue job to extract and transform the data from Oracle and load it to MariaDB? Can I do that in Glue or do I need to use a Data Store like S3 to store the data that I pull from Oracle? I have like 2500 tables so I think it would be a lot to store in S3.

Also I would use Lambda to automate the Glue jobs and trigger them. I guess my question is how the pipeline would work for this type of incremental load because I can't go directly from Oracle -> Glue -> MariaDB right?

Comment: confused.  it sounds like you have an oracle database, but you also talk about creating (another?) one?  is this data you are migrating once?  or regularly?  or trying to replicate live?

Answer (score 0):

Rather tha using glue to perform this migration. I suggest you use AWS's service dedicated to database migration called DMS - Database Migration Service

More on : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/index.html